# JSON NSNumber returning incorrectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, nsnumber

I am starting out with JSON with Objective-C, I have retrieved data from the server and am being given an `NSDictionary` as expected.

As an example, here are two values in my dictionary.

`length` and `start`.

`length` returns as expected, an `NSNumber`, `268`. However, `start` also apparently an `NSNumber` (which I would expect it to be though) is chucking a great long string of numbers, as though it isn't formatting properly.

E.g. `start` = `1423113951`.

How can I be certain of the data type I am receiving? That it is getting parsed correctly? And how I should handle it on my end?

I know that `start` is a number and it should return similarly to `length` but the long number I get is almost the same every runtime, so it clearly isn't formatting properly.

I get these value by simply logging the `NSDictionary` I get back from:

`NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];`

Some extra detail, here is my request for the data:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://secretAddress"]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

Understandably it could potentially be how the server is sending it back to me, but currently I do not know how it is being sent.

Comment: What is the actual value passed to webservice, I mean start value?

Comment: How do you convert the value to an NSNumber If i'm not mistaken NSJSONSerialization returns strings as values

Comment: Added a little extra detail to show full code. Having received the dictionary I just logged `[json objectForKey:@"start"] class]` and it tells me it is an `NSNumber`. Or is that a potentially mis-interpretable?

Comment: hve u checked it server side also??

Comment: I don't control the server side unfortunately, waiting to hear on their developer to see how they send that number for clarification. However, in a typical JSON case that data is fine for them, so I am led to believe it is how I am getting the data, or it is being parsed. Chance there is a better JSON parser than Apples own?

Comment: I suggest you to try something else then just apple, I would try with Advanced REST client for verification of data.

Comment: interesting suggestion @NickCatib as I hadn't heard of that before. I tried the same request in Advanced REST client and I am getting the same result. So this could be server side. Hmmmm.

Comment: Yeah, it is really usefull for testing REST APIs you are depending on, that could save you a lot of time... Seems like server issue indeed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I've had issues parsing JSON data, the first thing I'd do is to put a breakpoint on the line of code where I'm parsing the number, and examine the contents of my NSDictionary item:

[image]

As you can see in this example, XCode has reported that the `NoteID` from my JSON web service is an `NSNumber`, but it's happy to let me extract its value into an `int`.

So, start there: check the contents of your web service's data, and see if that points you in the right direction.